# How do I add the value_counts for two columns, on each row of a DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, networkx

I have this [DataFrame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P7PwB.png) that I have taken from another DataFrame. It has the start station for a bike trip and an end station. I plan to add them to a network using networkx and from_pandas_dataframe(). I just need to make another Series/column for the weights.

I want for each row to find the [value_counts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DN4Xk.png) for each start station and end station and add them together as a weight.

So for first entry I would find the occurrences for stations 3058 and 3082, add them and place the result on the weights column like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vj3iD.png).

EDIT: Adding code as requested:

```
df = data[['start_station','end_station']]
a = df.start_station.value_counts()
b = df.end_station.value_counts()
pd.options.display.max_rows=300
c = a + b
```

And here's the dataset: https://ufile.io/cxbov

Comment: Hey and welcome to SO. Please try to post your actual code here instead of images. You can check out [ask] for more guidance.

Comment: Also it would be nice if you could add small input data sample and the expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
df = pd.read_csv('metro.csv')

s = df[['start_station','end_station']].apply(pd.value_counts).sum(1)

df_out = df[['start_station','end_station']].assign(weight = df['start_station'].map(s) + df['end_station'].map(s))

print(df_out.head())
```

Output:

```
   start_station  end_station  weight
0           3058         3082    6248
1           3058         3082    6248
2           4147         4174     496
3           4157         4162     903
4           3013         3013     100
```